# Is there a way to make apt-get upgrade not show changelogs?

Tags: linux, apt, raspbian

I want to be able to script `apt-get upgrade` to run seamlessly without prompts, but in my experiments, I can't get it to stop showing prompts, even with `-y` or `--force yes`. Lately, when setting up RPis from scratch, this is an example offender that I simply have to hit `q` to continue with the upgrade:

```
ca-certificates (20141019+deb8u2) stable; urgency=medium

  Update Mozilla certificate authority bundle to version 2.9.
    The following certificate authorities were added (+):
    + "Certplus Root CA G1"
    + "Certplus Root CA G2"
    + "Certum Trusted Network CA 2"
    + "Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions ECC RootCA 2015"
    + "Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions RootCA 2015"
    + "ISRG Root X1"
    + "OpenTrust Root CA G1"
    + "OpenTrust Root CA G2"
    + "OpenTrust Root CA G3"
    + "SZAFIR ROOT CA2"
    The following certificate authorities were removed (-):
    - "CA Disig"
    - "NetLock Business (Class B) Root"
    - "NetLock Express (Class C) Root"
    - "NetLock Notary (Class A) Root"
    - "NetLock Qualified (Class QA) Root"
    - "Sonera Class 1 Root CA"
    - "Staat der Nederlanden Root CA"
    - "Verisign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2"
    - "Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority"
    - "Verisign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2"

 -- Michael Shuler <michael@pbandjelly.org>  Fri, 18 Nov 2016 09:09:47 -0600
```

Honestly, this is annoying even when I'm manually running the program as it can take several minutes and I will walk off, expecting to come back to a completed task and only find it to be paused part way through.

I saw something about making it quieter with `-qq` or something, but I'm a bit afraid it might overwrite a conf file that differs from defaults (while annoying, I find that to be acceptable).

So, honestly, I don't even know how to ask the right question - I just want this prompt gone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output you are seeing comes from the `apt-listchanges` package, which is not default. There are multiple ways you can prevent the changes from pausing the update process:

1. Set `APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=cat` in the environment
2. Edit `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf` and set `frontend=cat` under the `apt` section
3. Uninstall the `apt-listchanges` package

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual of 'apt-listchanges' you can configure apt using different frontends. To print changelogs to standard output, you should use 'text' frontend. You can also suppress change logs using 'none' frontend.